# How to clean up multiple spaces/linebreaks?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a variable `summary` like this:

```
T    he  
Fox


Jumped



    Over
```

There are 3 parts to clean `summary`:

- 2+ Consecutive spaces should become 1 space, see below `T he`
- 2+ Consecutive line breaks should become 2 line breaks, see vertical spacing below
- Tabs should be removed.

The goal is:

```
T he  
Fox

Jumped    

Over
```

**Note:** I tried `summary.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');` but it outputted `T he Fox Jumped Over`, which took care of the first part, but totally destroyed the vertical spacing on the second part, as it considers it consecutive spacing. Tabs should also be removed/cleaned up if they exist.

How can I get the goal?

**Update:** I think I screwed up on part 2, with the # of line breaks, so I updated it. But the goal is what we're after in terms of spacing/formatting.

Comment: Fwiw: this `<BOL><space><space><space><space>Over` becomes `<BOL><space>Over`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
summary.replace(/ +/g, ' ').replace(/\n\n+/g, "\n\n").replace(/\t+/g, '');
```

Comment: @JefréN. OP didn't say anything about tabs.

Comment: Sorry, I added an update, but the goal isn't what it looks like. Tabs still exist, and the vertical spacing of line breaks isn't the same (my fault so I added the update, but as long as the goal is output should be good to go)

Comment: @Wonka, ok - updated to remove tabs and replace 2+ `\n` with 2 `\n`.

Comment: Just wondering, is it possible to combine them into one replace somehow, or is this the most efficient way?

Comment: @Wonka if you try to you will get an unreadable mess. It is probably possible, but I doubt it will be any more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Two+ consecutive spaces or line breaks.

Find `((?:[ ]|\r?\n))\1+`
Replace `$1` or `\1` which ever your engine uses.

**edit:** to remove all tabs as well.
(*Note - when tabs match, capture group 1 will be empty.

Result: tabs get removed, not replaced. Use the same replace.*)

Find `(?:\t+|((?:[ ]|\r?\n))\1+)`
Replace `$1` or `\1`

**edit2:** 2+ line breaks become 2 line breaks.
(More add on, OP keeps changing it)

Find `(?:\t+|((?:[ ](?=[ ])|(?:\r?\n){2}))\1*)`
Replace `$1` or `\1`

---

Requires only 1 pass and is the fastest way

Answer (score 1):

```
summary.replace(/([ \n\t])\1+/g, '$1');
```

or if you all white space characters

```
summary.replace(/(\s)\1+/g, '$1');
```

This is more efficient as it does a single pass over the string.

Comment: What's that `\1` for?

Comment: `\1` means "match whatever text was matched by the first parentheses"

Comment: Ok. That answers my next question ... I'd never seen that before. +!

Comment: You shouldn't replace line breaks/tabs with a space character.

Comment: Sorry, added an update, the tabs are removed perfectly, but the vertical spacing/line breaks doesn't look like the goal...

Comment: @Wonka now that you've changed your requirements, it cannot be done in a single pass. You use ndn's solution that does multiple passes.